# What is wrong with my code for CodeHS 8.3.7: Exlamat!on Po!nts?

Tags: python

This is what I'm supposed to do:
Words are way more fun when you replace the letter ‘i’ with an exclamation point!

Write a program that asks the user for a string and then prints the same string with every lowercase i replaced with an exclamation point. Your program should:

Convert the initial string to a list
Use a `for` loop to go through your list element by element 
Whenever you see a lowercase i, replace it with an exclamation point in the list
Print the stringified version of the list when your `for` loop is finished
Here’s what an example run of your program might look like:

`Enter text: I like music.
I l!ke mus!c.`

This is my code right now:

```
my_string = input("Enter text: ")
my_list = list(my_string)
for item in my_list:
    if item == "i":
        print "!"
        my_list.remove("i")
    print item
(" ").join(my_list)
```

The problem with my code is that instead of replacing `i` with `!`, it adds the `!`, keeps the `i` and removes the letter after `i`. How do I fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to leverage `enumerate()` to change list items:

```
my_string = list(input('Enter string: '))
for i, char in enumerate(my_string):
    if char == 'i':
        my_string[i] == '!'
print(''.join(my_string))
```

It is usually not the best to remove list items during iteration, but this approach keeps track of what item we’re at and we can edit it using the list index, `i`.

Better yet, use a list comprehension and a ternary if statement:

```
my_string = list(input('Enter text: '))
my_string = ['!' if char == 'i' else char
             for char in my_string]
print(''.join(my_string))
```

Answer (score 3):

Entering the if clause does not prevent the 'i' from being printed.

Imagine the scenario where item == 'i'. It will match the if clause and proceed to printing '!' and removing an 'i' from my_list. However. item is still 'i', and will be printed by print item

You could modify the code to print item only when it's not an i.

```
my_string = input("Enter text: ")
my_list = list(my_string)
for item in my_list:
    if item == "i":
        print "!"
        my_list.remove("i")
    else:
        print item
(" ").join(my_list)
```

Better yet, if you don't need to save my_list for posterity, you don't even need to remove 'i' characters from my_list. So you could probably live without the following lines.

```
my_list.remove("i")
```

and

```
(" ").join(my_list)
```